# Нужно сравнить 2 больших списка номеров и выделить отличающиеся номера

Tags: excel, сравнение, csv

Нужно сравнить 2 больших списка номеров и выделить отличающиеся номера.

**Дано:**

Есть 5-6 *.csv файлов со списками мобильных номеров типа 12345678912.
В каждом файле около 1 млн. номеров в одном столбце. Т.е. всего 5-6 млн. номеров.

**Нужно:**

**1)** Объединить эти файлы в один. Excel не позволяет добавить в один файл больше 1 млн. строк.
В какой программе это можно сделать? И также нужно удалить там дубликаты номеров.
**2)** Будет 2-й файл с примерно таким же кол-вом номеров.
Нужно сравнить эти 2 файла по примерно 6 млн. номеров и сформировать 3-й файл (или список с номерами) где будут только номера, которых нету в 1-м файле.

Я не программист и в коде не разбираюсь. Прошу подсказать программу (Microsoft Access, что-то из SQL и т.д.) с помощью которой это можно сделать и инструкцию как.

Так же возможно кто-то знает сервисы, где это можно сделать онлайн?

2 человека загружают 2 разных файла в одну сессию, без возможности посмотреть или скачать чужой файл. Сравнивают их, видят результат и второй человек высылает 3-й файл (с результатом уникальных значений) 1-му человеку.

Заранее большое спасибо за советы и наводки.

Comment: В принципе да, если слить все в одну базу (Access, MS SQL Server или другое - не знаю, что используется на сервере, куда загружаются файлы), то из базы эта информация получается одним SQL запросом.

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего сохранить эти списки в текстовом файле: одна строка - одна запись.

А дальше обработать их с помощью утилит коммандной строки. В Линуксе и Мак это есть из коробки. В Виндовс надой найти и поставить. Или если есть возможность воспользоваться любым хостингом на линуксе, где есть возможность зайти по SSH.

Утилита `uniq`

Вызов

```
 uniq -u filename.txt > myfile.txt
```

Выведет в файл **myfile.txt*** только уникальные строки из файла **filename.txt**

Таким образом решается задача номер раз.

После этого сливаете свой файл с полученным файлом в один. И делаете опять поиск уникальных строк:

```
uniq -u summary.txt > delta.txt
```

В файле **delta.txt** получаете уникальные строки. Но здесь есть как строки которые есть в первом файле, но которых нет во втором, так и наоборот.

Дальше сливаете этот файл с вашим первоначальным - и сделав еще раз

uniq -u summ.txt > newfile.txt

Получаете в файле **newfile.txt** новый список, который включает в себя ваши старые номера и те номера из другого файла, которых у вас до этого не было.

Answer (score 0):

Ограничения MS Excel по обработке больших csv файлов можно обойти применяя язык R и среду RStudio. Привожу завершенный фрагмент кода для решения задачи:

```
# Работающий код на примере трех файлов:
# a.csv, b.csv, c.csv - файлы для демонстрации работы кода для 1-ой части вопроса;
# в результате обработки a.csv и b.csv получим файл содержащий только уникальные значения 
# z.csv - файл для демонстрации работы кода для 2-ой части вопроса
#
# Код очень примитивен
# подключаем библиотеку для манипуляции данными
library(dplyr)

# создаем общий файл из нескольких
# создаем Таблицы данных с содержимым файлов
file_a <- "D:/Tmp/R-cmprFls/a.csv"
df_temp_a <- read.csv(file_a, head=TRUE, sep="|", dec=",")

file_b <- "D:/Tmp/R-cmprFls/b.csv"
df_temp_b <- read.csv(file_b, head=TRUE, sep="|", dec=",")

file_c <- "D:/Tmp/R-cmprFls/c.csv"
df_temp_c <- read.csv(file_c, head=TRUE, sep="|", dec=",")

# для добавления количества обрабатываемых файлов 
# добавляем строки file_xxx, df_temp_xxx 

# объединяем все Таблицы данных в одну
join_df_temp <- bind_rows(df_temp_a, df_temp_b, df_temp_c)

# для определения уникальных строк в Таблице данных используем группировку 
# и ссумирование по полю Number
# добавляем поле Cnt - для подсчета одинаковых Number
mt_df_temp <- mutate(join_df_temp, Cnt = 1)

# группируем по полю Number и суммируем по полю Cnt
gr_df_temp <- group_by(mt_df_temp, Number)
sm_df_temp <- summarise(gr_df_temp, Cnt = sum(Cnt))

# уникальными являются строки со значением поля Cnt = 1
rslt_1_df_temp <- filter(sm_df_temp, Cnt == 1)

# сохраняем результат для 1-ой части вопроса
write.table(rslt_1_df_temp, file = "D:/Tmp/R-cmprFls/rslt_1_df_temp.csv",    row.names = FALSE)

# 2-я часть. Объединяем результат 1-ой части с эталонным файлом 
# создаем Таблицу даных на основании z.csv
file_z <- "D:/Tmp/R-cmprFls/z.csv"
df_temp_z <- read.csv(file_z, head=TRUE, sep="|", dec=",")

mt_df_temp_z <- mutate(df_temp_z, Cnt=1)

# создаем результирующую Таблицу данных в соответствии с требованиями 
# для 2-ой части вопроса
rslt_2_df_temp <- anti_join(mt_df_temp_z, rslt_1_df_temp)
# сохраняем результат
write.table(rslt_2_df_temp, file = "D:/Tmp/R-cmprFls/rslt_2_df_temp.csv",    row.names = FALSE)
```

Данные файлов

**a.csv**

```
Number
1111111111
2222222222
3333333333
4444444444
5555555555
6666666666
```

**b.csv**

```
Number
1111111111
2222222222
3333333333
7777777777
8888888888
9999999999
```

**c.csv**

```
Number
1111111111
2222222222
3333333333
7777777777
8888888888
9999999999
```

**z.csv**

```
Number
1111111111
2222222222
4444444444
5555555555
7777777777
8080808080
9090909090
```

результаты:

**rslt_1_df_temp**

```
"Number" "Cnt"
4444444444 1
5555555555 1
6666666666 1
```

**rslt_2_df_temp**

```
"Number" "Cnt"
8080808080 1
9090909090 1
2222222222 1
1111111111 1
7777777777 1
```